# How to export a pointcloud to be view in matlab

Tags: python, matlab, opencv

I use the OpenCV function

```
pointCloud = cv2.reprojectImageTo3D(filteredImg,disparityToDepthMap) / 420
```

to get an pointcloud of my stereo images.

I want to show it into matlab, I tried to load the data into matlab but i failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to save variables to be read later in Matlab, I recommend to store them as .mat documents executing the following line in python:

```
import scipy.io as spio

spio.savemat(r'C:\DirectoryNameofMatlabProject' , mdict={'namedata': namedata})
```

Once stored the .mat containing the desired data, in your case "pointCloud", you will need to open the .mat in Matlab. For this, just click in "Import Data".

Finally, in order to transform this data into a pointCloud object in Matlab, execute the following code:

```
ptCloud=pointCloud(namedata);

pcshow(namedata)
```

I hope you find it helpful.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks for your answer. this brings me one step forward!
but the result ist very confusing. it shows me nothing which would make sense....But the disparity Image is really good and right

Comment: could you add a picture of your point cloud if possible? I would like what it looks like, so maybe we could find a better way of helping you... I suppose that you original point cloud is in 3 dimensions, right?

Comment: [disparity Image](https://www.imagebanana.com/s/1420/3V75Wvm4.html)
[matlab](https://www.imagebanana.com/s/1420/VgFkc2R6.html)
[orginal](https://www.imagebanana.com/s/1420/Y35Jatoo.html) I use the [SBGM](http://timosam.com/python_opencv_depthimage) -method to create it (but of course with rectifying!)

Comment: okay i see the fault...i zoom out tooooo much [the relevant Region](https://www.imagebanana.com/s/1420/Bko0Quk2.html) is very near. so it make a little bit more sense, but there all still some confusing areas....is there any possibilty to get the imagecolour to the matlab file?

Comment: Great you managed to see something! I don't know how to get the image colour to the Matlab file tough :(  . Maybe the color code is stored in other variable and you can export it to Matlab in the same way (just brains storming)...

Comment: thanks for your help! I'll study now the image...maybe there is some sense hidden ;)